# How to apply certificates for Remote Desktop Services farm

Tags: certificate, remote, remote-desktop-services

I've been chasing my tail for a while trying to apply certificates to servers in my server farm for Server 2012 R2.

Here is my environment:

I have 1 Broker Server, 3 Session Hosts. I've assigned a dns entry "farm" to point to Broker Server. What happens now is the typical "The certificate is not from a trusted certifying authority error" and gives me the name of the broker server. When I click yes to trust I then get a second screen for the session host with the same message and I click yes on that in order to finally log in to a host in the farm.

My desired outcome:

I would like to eliminate both of these certificate warnings and just type in the name "farm" and have rdp connect me straight to the host.

How can I achieve my desired outcome? This for an internal environment. I am using Server 2003 SP2 as my CA. Assuming the solution has to be done with CA. Purchasing or obtaining a Cert from an outside provider is not an option.

Thank You All